# How can code detect if running inside an animation frame?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

If some function is passed into `requestAnimationFrame()`, how can that function detect that it is being called inside an animation frame?

f.e.

```
function someFunction() {
  if (/* What goes here? */) {
    console.log('Inside animation frame.')
  }
  else {
    console.log('Not inside animation frame.')
  }
}

// The following lines should not be modified for the answer.
someFunction() // logs "Not inside animation frame."
requestAnimationFrame(someFunction) // eventually logs "Inside animation frame."
```

The last two lines should not be modified. I am interested to know if I can detect the situation without requiring the user to remember to use the function two different ways. The end user should just use the function like normal, without knowing that my function detects the use case.

Comment: You could always pass something in from the call site: `requestAnimationFrame(function(){someFunction(true)})` vs `someFunction(false)`.

Comment: That's true, but if my function is given to other people to use, there is no guarantee that they will do that. Or, other people might not even know that they are calling this function indirectly.

Comment: ES6 default parameters might help with that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: @spender That might be the best answer so far, but it's still not 100% for certain. For example, if we define `function someFunction(time = false) {}`, then `time` will a timestamp when in a frame, and `false` outside of the frame (except if the user passes a manual value for the timestamp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `bind` your function that you pass to `requestAnimationFrame`.

```
function someFunction(isInsideAnimationFrame, domHighResTimestamp) {
  if (isInsideAnimationFrame) {
    console.log('Inside animation frame.')
  }
  else {
    console.log('Not inside animation frame.')
  }
}

someFunction() // logs "Not inside animation frame."

requestAnimationFrame(someFunction.bind(null, true)) // eventually logs "Inside animation frame."
```

See [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for details on how it works.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the docs for [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) the callback i.e. `someFunction` will be called with a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` which is .

`someFunction` could detect this with

```
function someFunction(domHighResTimestamp) {
  if (domHighResTimestamp) {
    console.log('Inside animation frame.')
  }
  else {
    console.log('Not inside animation frame.')
  }
}
```

Unfortunately there's no guarantee that whoever uses `someFunction` doesn't call it passing a value.

Comment: Hi phuzi, similar to spender's comments, the user of my function may or may not do that. If it was strictly my own code, then yeah, that would be easy. I'll update the question.

Comment: Updated my question: the last two lines in the example should not be modified.

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative. I'm not sure there's a 100% foolproof way to detect what you want though.

Comment: Accepted your answer, but put mine for reference, based also on @Archer's polyfill idea.

Comment: @trusktr If your answer fulfills your needs accept that instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's not currently possible to get the context of the calling code in Javascript, so you can't do what you want unless you change `requestAnimationFrame()`, but thankfully you can do that.  Try this...

```js
// save a reference to the existing method and then override it...
window._requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback) {
 return window._requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  callback(true);
 });
}

function someFunction() {
 if (arguments.length && arguments[0]) {
  console.log('Inside animation frame.')
 }
 else {
  console.log('Not inside animation frame.')
 }
}

someFunction();
requestAnimationFrame(someFunction);
```

Comment: Most likely the OP will need a polyfill anyway, so that would be simple to add.

Comment: Bit of overkill - the callback will be called with a single argument, `DOMHighResTimeStamp`, if called in the context of an animation frame.

Comment: Good idea. But funny thing is in your particular example it still works without the monkey patch.

Comment: phuzi beat me to it: yep, because of the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, for the polyfill idea (although intrusive, I suppose it works). See my own answer for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Putting my own answer here for reference (thanks @phuzi, @Archer, and @spender):

```js
// save a reference to the existing method and then override it...
window.requestAnimationFrame = function (raf) { return function(callback) {
  return raf(function(time) {
    callback(time, true);
  });
}}(window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window))

function someFunction(time, inFrame = false) {
  if (inFrame) {
    console.log('Inside animation frame.')
  }
  else {
    console.log('Not inside animation frame.')
  }
}

someFunction(); // logs "Not inside animation frame."
someFunction(63245); // still logs "Not inside animation frame."
requestAnimationFrame(someFunction); // eventually logs "Inside animation frame."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

It exports `getIsDuringAnimationFrame` and patches native `requestAnimationFrame` function.

```
let animationFrameCallbacksCount = 0;

const originalRequestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window);

window.requestAnimationFrame = function requestAnimationFrame(callback: (time: number) => void) {
  return originalRequestAnimationFrame((time) => {
    try {
      animationFrameCallbacksCount++;
      callback(time);
    } finally {
      animationFrameCallbacksCount--;
    }
  })
}

export function getIsDuringAnimationFrame() {
  return animationFrameCallbacksCount > 0;
}
```